# jQuery "$.ajax" code dont work, syntax error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

i post because i spend a lot of time for understanding why my code isnt working...

i try to get json data with jQuery, i see somes exemple working very well but mine do not...

```js
$("#go").click(function(){
 var sumName = $("#playername").attr("value");
 var region = $("#playerregion").attr("value");
 console.log(sumName);
 console.log(region);

/********* Working without this part *********/  
 if ( sumName !== "" ) {
 
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + region + "/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + sumName + "?api_key=MYAPIKEYIDONTSHOWYOU",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { }
        });

  success: function (json) {
   var sumNameNoSpace =  sumName.replace(" ", ""),
   sumID = json[sumNameNoSpace].id;
   console.log(sumID);
        }
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) ({
                alert("error getting Summoner data!");
      });
    }
     else {}
/*************************************************/

$("#lolskill iframe").attr("src", "http://www.lolskill.net/game/"+ region +"/"+ sumName);
$("#lolnexus iframe").attr("src", "http://www.lolnexus.com/"+ region + "/search?name="+ sumName +"&region="+ region);

})
```

For more info i try to get json data from League of legend API system, i the hmtl the user can give summoners name(id playername) + this region(id playerregion). i want to get the data id in the json, but my code make bug all the file i think.

I try a lot of different syntax but no result. i have start the javacript/jQuery for now 4 days and i feel completly lost.

Please help a Noob! :)

Comment: can you post, what error are you getting ?

Answer (score 1):

You are ending the ajax call before all of the options are completed

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + region + "/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + sumName + "?api_key=MYAPIKEYIDONTSHOWYOU",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { },
//You ended it here, it should be further down. });
    success: function (json) {
        var sumNameNoSpace =  sumName.replace(" ", ""),
        sumID = json[sumNameNoSpace].id;
        console.log(sumID);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){//removed '('
            alert("error getting Summoner data!");
    }
});//Should end here
```

Comment: Thank you it's working... i really need training to see theses things... spend like 4 hours on that lol.

Comment: Happens to the best of us, sometimes just needs fresh eyes to spot the problem.

Answer (score -1):

First, keep your `success` & `error` callbacks in ajax call. This is syntex mismatch..please correct.
Second,
`data:{}` should be serialized in json string.

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + region + "/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + sumName + "?api_key=MYAPIKEYIDONTSHOWYOU",
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "json",
     data: JSON.stringify({}),
     success: function (json) {
        var sumNameNoSpace =  sumName.replace(" ", ""),
        sumID = json[sumNameNoSpace].id;
        console.log(sumID);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) ({
            alert("error getting Summoner data!");
     }
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Your success and error handlers should be inside the $.ajax call. Also, I would do `alert(XMLHttpReqeust.responseText)` in your error handler as that will give you a better better idea of what's going wrong when you do have problems.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + region + "/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + sumName + "?api_key=MYAPIKEYIDONTSHOWYOU",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{}",
        success: function (json) {
        var sumNameNoSpace =  sumName.replace(" ", "");
        sumID = json[sumNameNoSpace].id;
        console.log(sumID);
    },
     error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) ({
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    });
```

Comment: What's the problem with the answer I've provided?

Answer (score -1):

Certainly, you have a syntax error. You should invoke "success" and "error" callbacks from the body of your AJAX call (I mean, before you type the parenthesis ")"). Furthermore, from the jQuery API Documentation:

> The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are
>   deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual
>   removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

This should work fine:

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + region + "/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + sumName + ",
    type: "GET",
    data: ({
        api_key: "MYAPIKEYIDONTSHOWYOU"
    }).done(function(json){
        var sumNameNoSpace =  sumName.replace(" ", ""),
        sumID = json[sumNameNoSpace].id;
        console.log(sumID);
    }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("error getting Summoner data!");
        console.log(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
    }).always(function(){
        console.log("The AJAX request has been completed!")
    });
});
```